# How to remove � in Coldfusion JSON?

Tags: json, coldfusion

When I create JSON feed and output it in browser, I don't know why that character � coming up in every single character?

```
{"members": [
{"user":"���d���e���8���8���f���5���c���7���3���7���1���4���7���6���6���f", "username":"���P���P���S���h���e���i���n", "avatar":"���m���a���l���e���.���p���n���g"} 
]}
```

Here is my Coldfusion coding,

```
<cfcontent type="application/json; charset=utf-8">
<cfoutput query="getTrackQry">
{"members": [
{"user":"#tuser#", "username":"#tusername#", "avatar":"#tpicture#"} <cfif currentrow LT getTrackQry.recordcount>,</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Even it's correctly display in mysql.

[image]

Comment: Is your query has the correct characters or the same string with these characters?

Comment: it's correctly displaying in mysql. Please check my question.

Comment: I have tried the same piece of code with another query. It is working fine. Try dumping the query. If it is ok, then you might have some Charset or meta issue

Comment: @ppshein which encoding does your database use?

Comment: @MarikkaniChelladurai your comment remind me to check encoding to fix correct. Can you post it as ansnwer? I'm gonna marked as correct answer.

Comment: @adnankamili can u post it as answer? If then yes, I'm vote up your answer.

Comment: @ppshein added as an answer

Comment: try using the code reReplace(tuser, "[^\x20-\x7E]", "", "ALL")>

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have tried the same piece of code with another query. It is working fine. Try dumping the query. If it is ok, then you might have some encoding issue. Please ensure that the encoding method is causing the problem.

Comment: Please mention the exact issue and the fix too

Comment: That's not really a helpful answer to the question.

Comment: It's because of I have not assigned utf-8 encoding format in my sql column field.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like an encoding issue in database. Make sure you are using a proper encoding most probably utf8